# Anylogic gives an error for creating a path

Tags: anylogic

i want to connect two nodes with a path that goes trough a pallet rack,but every time i try,it appears this error (see image):
[image: error]

Afterwards,it gives me a path between the nodes, but it's curved.
Any suggestions?Thanks

Comment: Paths through pallet racks need to go cleanly through the middle corridor so it is highlighted green. Did you make sure your path does that?

Comment: I'm sure. no node is in the "green zone" of the pallet rack

Comment: add some screenshots. Before, after, of that path 26... :)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the network,i noticed a second existing path under the image,linked to the same nodes. deleting it, the new path has not given the same error.